# How do I remove my bindings?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Using Knockout, It's pretty simple to populate a loop with some json data.Here's the loop in the view:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: VacationRequestNotes">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <span class="input-sm" style="white-space:nowrap;" data-bind="text: EmployeeName"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
         <span class="input-sm" data-bind="text: NoteText"></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

And then the script:

```
function ViewNotes(vactionRequestId) {
    $.getJSON("/VacationRequests/GetNotes", { VacationRequestId: vactionRequestId }, function (data) {
        if (data != "error") {
            ko.applyBindings({
                VacationRequestNotes: data
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This works great!  At least, the first time.  The second time, I get

> Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

I've seen other threads here that say I need to remove the bindings, but I'm having a hard time applying those examples to what I'm doing.

```
function ViewNotes(vactionRequestId) {
    $.getJSON("/VacationRequests/GetNotes", { VacationRequestId: vactionRequestId }, function (data) {
        if (data != "error") {
            ko.applyBindings({
                VacationRequestNotes: data
            });
            ko.cleanNode(??? WHAT DO I PUT HERE ???);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried approaching it from the other end and not applying your bindings from within a repeating block of code? You can apply them once at document ready, and update existing observables within the ajax callback.

Comment: Try to do this `ko.cleanNode(document.getElementsByTagName("body"));`

Comment: @Jason Solake: ok -- yeah, I was thinking along the same lines. New to knockout. Trying to figure out how to do that.  When the page first loads, VacationRequestNotes will be null.  It's not until a user clicks on a "view notes" button that it will contain anything.  So what do I bind it to at document ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working:

```
  $(document).on('ready',
        function () {
            masterVM = new VacationRequestsViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(masterVM);
        });

    function VacationRequestsViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.VacationRequestNotes = ko.observableArray();

        self.ViewNotes = function (vactionRequestId) {
            $.getJSON("/VacationRequests/GetNotes", { VacationRequestId: vactionRequestId }, function (data) {
                if (data != "error") {
                    self.VacationRequestNotes(data)
                    $("#modalNotes").modal('show');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Then, in the HTML, instead of this link:

```
<a href="" onclick="ViewNotes(3)">View Notes</a>
```

Just change it to:

```
<a href="" onclick="masterVM.ViewNotes(3)">View Notes</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ViewNotes() {
        var self = this;    
        self.VacationRequestNotes = ko.observable();
        self.GetNotes = function(vactionRequestId) {        
        $.getJSON("/VacationRequests/GetNotes", { VacationRequestId: vactionRequestId }, function (data) {
            if (data != "error") {
               self.VacationRequestNotes(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)); //requires the ko mapping.          
               //In vanilla JS you can use the map function. 
            }
        });     
    }    
}   

$(function() {  
    var vm = new ViewNotes();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);   
});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for this!  One question: How is GetNotes ever executed?

Comment: vm.GetNotes(someParameter). Or you can bind it to a button or a link. I can help you to do that.

Comment: after ko.applyBindings(vm)

Comment: Yes, binding it to a link is exactly what I need to do.  Right now I have link that is `onclick=ViewNotes(45)`, for example

Comment: Instead of onclick you should use the knockout attribute <button type="button" data-bind="click: GetNotes">Click</button>. The foreach loop will pass the current item to the GetNotes function.